# How to speed up getting result from large collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm working with MongoDB and I want to display last 10 entries in collection, which should be ordered by score. The problem is that there is about 2 million entries so each query takes up from 5-7 sec.

Things were working pretty good when the database was smaller but with increasing size problems occurred. I checked `.explain('executionStats')` and I noticed that in result there is `nReturened: 10` and `totalDocsExamined: 1959933` which means that it is going through whole database to return last 10 entries. (also `totalKeysExamined: 0` if someone needs that info)

Searching query looks like this:
`db.logs.find({}).sort({"score":-1}).limit(10).toArray()`
Stages of query are `COLLSCAN, SORT_KEY_GENERATOR, SORT`

I'm aware that `find({})` is going through whole DB, then sorting it, and getting last 10 results. But what should be the better way to speed the things up?

Comment: you could use `cursor`'s, when there is huge amount of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an index on `{score: 1}` will help greatly.  Mongo definitely uses index for sorting if available.  You should see IXSCAN, FETCH, and LIMIT stages after creating the index.

Comment: mongo engine is intelligent enough to use index `{score: 1}` even you sort by `{score -1}`.  Try it yourselft.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create index on key you are performing search in mongodb.
Indexing will help you to retrieve data faster.

Use: `db.collection.createIndex(keys, options)`

For more information please read the doc [MongoDB create index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/)

Hope this will help. Good luck!

Comment: Hi, thank you for you answer. But isn't creating index helpful only when searching? Because I'm not performing specific search based on any of "columns" but selecting all of the data from DB and then sorting it.

Comment: Try db.collection.mapReduce(). check: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/map-reduce/